# No pagechange event firing

Tags: javascript, jquery, events, mobile, jquery-mobile

In jQuery mobile, I am trying to detect a successful page change to a specific page. I have the following code, inline on the page I want to load.

```
<script>
     $(document).bind( "pagebeforechange", function( e, data ) {
            alert("pagebeforechange");   
        });

        $(document).bind( "pagechange", function( e, data ) {
            alert("pagechange");   
        });
        $(document).bind( "pagechangefailed", function( e, data ) {
            alert("pagechangefailed");   
        });
       $(document).live( "pagebeforechange", function( e, data ) {
            alert("pagebeforechange live");   
        });

        $(document).live( "pagechange", function( e, data ) {
            alert("pagechange live");   
        });
        $(document).live( "pagechangefailed", function( e, data ) {
            alert("pagechangefailed live");   
        });
</script>
```

I get the the appropriate alerts when loading the page directly, or refreshing, but not when navigating from another area in the Jquery Mobile app.

Page is called by the the "Your Car" Tab in the footer

```
<div  id="footer" data-role="footer" data-position="fixed"> 
    <div data-role="navbar">
        <ul>
            <li><a href="index.html">Home</a></li>
            <li><a href="index.html">Features</a></li>
            <li><a href="about.html">Your Car</a></li>
            <li><a href="index.html">Contact</a></li>
        </ul>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: How are you triggering the page change ? can you include some of your code ?

Comment: Have made that more explicit in the question, thanks.

Comment: Have you tried pageshow or pagebeforeshow page transition events? jQM Docs: http://jquerymobile.com/demos/1.0.1/docs/api/events.html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Would it work to place your code in the pageshow event? It may if you are trying to detect the page or location. Something like this maybe:

```
<script type="text/javascript">

$('[data-role=page]').live('pageshow', function (event, ui) {
   hash = location.hash;
   page = hash.susbtr(1);

   if (page.indexOf('about.html') >= 0) { 
      alert('you made it!'); 
   }
});

</script>
```

**UPDATE**

After testing this scenario a bit more and rereading your question, I think I was able to reproduce the results.

This works as you described and only fires alerts when loading the page directly or refreshing the page:

```
<body>

<div data-role="page">
    <!-- page stuff -->
</div> 

<script type="text/javascript"> ..bind events... </script>
</body>
```

However, when I move the javascript directly inside the page, it works as expected and fires all of the bound events, no matter how the page was reached:

```
<body>

<div data-role="page">

    <script type="text/javascript"> ..bind events... </script>

    <!-- page stuff -->
</div> 

</body>
```

Comment: sort of the solution I have, but it's a hack, not a real solution.

Comment: well after testing it a bit, my solution doesn't work that well either. Would it help if you declared the script type -  `type="text/jasvascript"` ?

Comment: damn it, laptop is at work and I really want to try this!! will report back on Monday

Answer (score 0):

Where are you binding to this events?

Have you read following in the Docs http://code.jquery.com/mobile/latest/demos/docs/api/events.html:

> Important: Use pageInit(), not $(document).ready()
>
> The first thing you learn in jQuery is to call code inside the
>   $(document).ready() function so everything will execute as soon as the
>   DOM is loaded. However, in jQuery Mobile, Ajax is used to load the
>   contents of each page into the DOM as you navigate, and the DOM ready
>   handler only executes for the first page. To execute code whenever a
>   new page is loaded and created, you can bind to the pageinit event.
>   This event is explained in detail at the bottom of this page.

Comment: I am not using either. Having tested pageinit, it doesn't seem to work any better and on reading the docs, it seems pagechange is what I want

Comment: @MildFuzz with this i wanted to say, that maybe there where you bind to your events, it is to early...

Answer (score 0):

Luke's thinking is in the right direction: clearly the problem you had has to do with where in the code the binding is occurring.  This is proved by shanabus.

However, in your case, you should be doing the binding when jQuery mobile's `mobileinit` event is fired, not `pageInit`, as Luke is suggesting.

Example (fires on all page change events):

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).bind('mobileinit', function() {
        $(document).on('pagechange', function () {
            window.alert('page changed!');
        });
    });
</script>
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.2.0/jquery.mobile-1.2.0.js"></script>
```

As illustrated in the code above, be mindful that handlers triggered by `mobileinit` must be included **before** the jQuery mobile `<script>` tag.